# What series of intrinsics will complete this paeth prediction code?

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I have a Paeth Prediction function which operates on arrays:

```
std::array<std::uint8_t,4> birunji::paeth_prediction
    (const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& a,
     const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& b,
     const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& c)
{
    std::array<std::int16_t,4> pa;
    std::array<std::int16_t,4> pb;
    std::array<std::int16_t,4> pc;

    std::array<std::uint8_t,4> results;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        pa[i] = b[i] - c[i];
        pb[i] = a[i] - c[i];
        pc[i] = pa[i] + pb[i];

        pa[i] = std::abs(pa[i]);
        pb[i] = std::abs(pb[i]);
        pc[i] = std::abs(pc[i]);

        if(pa[i] <= pb[i] && pa[i] <= pc[i])
            results[i] = a[i];
        else if(pb[i] <= pc[i])
            results[i] = b[i];
        else
            results[i] = c[i];
    }

    return results;
}
```

I'm attempting to use intrinsics manually to vectorise the code (for learning purposes).

```
__m128i birunji::paeth_prediction(const __m128i& a,
                                  const __m128i& b,
                                  const __m128i& c)
{
    __m128i pa = _mm_sub_epi16(b, c);
    __m128i pb = _mm_sub_epi16(a, c);
    __m128i pc = _mm_add_epi16(pa, pb);
    
    pa = _mm_abs_epi16(pa);
    pb = _mm_abs_epi16(pb);
    pc = _mm_abs_epi16(pc);

    __m128i pa_le_pb = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pb, pa);
    __m128i pa_le_pc = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pc, pa);
    __m128i pb_le_pc = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pc, pb);

    return
    _mm_and_si128(_mm_and_si128(pa_le_pb, pa_le_pc),
                  _mm_and_si128(_mm_and_si128(pb_le_pc,b),a));
}
```

The trouble I'm having is the conditional statements. How do I successfully vectorize these? I'm not sure if my attempt above it correct.

Comment: `_mm_cmple_epi16_mask` is AVX512, can you use that? It seems odd, then, to use 128bit operations. Or perhaps you want something similar but with SSE2 operations?

Comment: @nicomp The code needs to use at least 16bits for the operations (the incoming `a`, `b`, and `c` are 8-bit numbers). Only the first 4 numbers are provided. However, I couldn't find a comparison function that used the 16bit numbers, hence why I looked in AVX2

Comment: SSE2 has `_mm_cmpgt_epi16`, `gt` is the exact opposite of `le` so it should be possible to use it

Comment: @nicomp thanks for the info. I've updated the question, I guess my problem is in combining the comparison operations to produce the correct vector.

Comment: Do you actually want to compute this for an array of 4, or for arbitrarily large ones?

Comment: @chtz specifically for an array of 4

Comment: I guess a 4 byte parallel Paeth would be useful for 32-bit PNG images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_mm_cmpgt_epi16` can be used for the comparisons. Note that `_mm_cmpgt_epi16(a, b) = !(a <= b)`, however `_mm_cmpgt_epi16(b, a) != (a <= b)`, because it is not a Greater or Equal comparison but a strict Greater Than comparison. So the masks come out inverted, but that's equally useful in this case, an explicit inversion won't be necessary.

This function should not return a condition itself, it should select from `a` and `b` and `c` according to the conditions. If SSE4.1 is available, `_mm_blendv_epi8` can be used to implement that selection. For example (not tested):

```
__m128i paeth_prediction(__m128i a, __m128i b, __m128i c)
{
    __m128i pa = _mm_sub_epi16(b, c);
    __m128i pb = _mm_sub_epi16(a, c);
    __m128i pc = _mm_add_epi16(pa, pb);
    
    pa = _mm_abs_epi16(pa);
    pb = _mm_abs_epi16(pb);
    pc = _mm_abs_epi16(pc);

    __m128i not_pa_le_pb = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pa, pb);
    __m128i not_pa_le_pc = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pa, pc);
    __m128i not_pb_le_pc = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pb, pc);
    __m128i not_take_a = _mm_or_si128(not_pa_le_pb, not_pa_le_pc);
    __m128i t = _mm_blendv_epi8(b, c, not_pb_le_pc);
    return _mm_blendv_epi8(a, t, not_take_a);
}
```

The last two lines implement logic like:

> if PB is not less-than-or-equal-to PC, take C, otherwise take B.
> if PA is not less-than-or-equal-to PB *or* PA is not less-than-or-equal-to PC, take the result from the previous step, otherwise take A.

Without SSE4.1, the blends could be implemented using AND/ANDNOT/OR.

I've changed the signature of the function so it takes the vectors by value, taking them by const reference is unnecessary (vectors are trivial to copy) and can add overhead from an indirection, though such overhead is likely to be removed if the function ends up being inlined by the compiler.

As a variant, `_mm_min_epi16` could be used to implement part of the logic:

```
__m128i paeth_prediction(__m128i a, __m128i b, __m128i c)
{
    __m128i pa = _mm_sub_epi16(b, c);
    __m128i pb = _mm_sub_epi16(a, c);
    __m128i pc = _mm_add_epi16(pa, pb);
    
    pa = _mm_abs_epi16(pa);
    pb = _mm_abs_epi16(pb);
    pc = _mm_abs_epi16(pc);

    __m128i not_pb_le_pc = _mm_cmpgt_epi16(pb, pc);
    __m128i take_a = _mm_cmpeq_epi16(pa, _mm_min_epi16(pa, _mm_min_epi16(pb, pc)));
    __m128i t = _mm_blendv_epi8(b, c, not_pb_le_pc);
    return _mm_blendv_epi8(t, a, take_a);
}
```

Because the condition `pa <= pb && pa <= pc` is equivalent to `pa == min(pa, pb, pc)`.

The resulting assembly code looks a bit better, but I did not test it in any way, including performance.

Comment: I guess the querent's code is assuming that the `abs()` inputs can't be SHORT_MIN, because they're treating the result as signed, not unsigned.  (That would be inconvenient to handle without AVX-512 unsigned compares).  It seems the original inputs are `uint8_t`, though, so I guess the 16-bit values are just zero-extended and will produce up to 9-bit signed differences.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes actually I thought about ways to avoid extending to 16-bit, it works partly but then there's trouble with `pc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your calculations by completely avoiding any conversion to `int16_t`.
First of all, note that `pa<=pc` as well as `pb<=pc` is true if and only if `a<=c<=b` or `b<=c<=a`. If `c` is smaller or equal than both, `max(a,b)` will be returned; if `c` is larger or equal, `min(a,b)` is returned.

So we can first "sort" `a`, `b` using a `min` and `max` operation,

```
A = min(a,b)
B = max(a,b)
```

which leaves three possible cases:

```
A<=B<=c  --> A
c<=A<=B  --> B
A< c< B  --> c
```

This means in C++ code

```
std::array<std::uint8_t,4> birunji::paeth_prediction
    (const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& a,
     const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& b,
     const std::array<std::uint8_t,4>& c)
{
    std::array<std::uint8_t,4> results;

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        uint8_t A = std::min(a[i],b[i]);
        uint8_t B = std::max(a[i],b[i]);
        if     (B<=c[i]) results[i] = A;
        else if(c[i]<=A) results[i] = B;
        else             results[i] = c[i];
    }

    return results;
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no unsigned SIMD comparison (before AVX-512), but we can simulate this using `(x<=y) == (max(x,y)==y)` (or doing a saturated subtracting and comparing with zero.

Possible (untested) SIMD-implementation (this would also work for arbitrarily many elements -- but you can just load four elements in the lowest 32 bits and ignore the rest of the result):

```
__m128i paeth_prediction(__m128i a, __m128i b, __m128i c)
{
    __m128i A = _mm_min_epu8(a, b);
    __m128i B = _mm_max_epu8(a, b);

    __m128i A_greater_equal_c = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_max_epu8(A, c), A);
    __m128i B_less_equal_c    = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(_mm_min_epu8(B, c), B);

    // if you don't have SSE 4.1, this can be done using bitwise and/or operations:
    __m128i t = _mm_blendv_epi8(b, c, A_greater_equal_c);
    return _mm_blendv_epi8(a, t, B_less_equal_c);
}
```

Comment: You can also simulate `x>y` unsigned with `(x^0x80) > (y^0x80)` signed.  But it's probably not better than min/cmp for this, since there's no chance to reuse range-shifted copies of A and B.  But can we use signed-saturating sub to get the sign bit of a byte set appropriately for pblendvb?  Without SSE4.1 you need the whole byte to be all-0/1, but with blend you only need the MSB.

Comment: No, my [`psubsb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psubsb:psubsw) idea won't work.  You'd need signed saturation of unsigned inputs.  You need `0 - 0xff` to signed-saturate to `0x80`, not `0 - (-1) = +1`.  Unsigned saturation isn't any more useful, AFAICS, still needing at least two instructions, and I don't think we get better back-end port distribution.

Comment: The `(x^0x80) > (y^0x80)` variant could on some architectures actually give slightly better throughput, since it runs on more ports (I don't think it is worth the extra uop in this case, though). Regarding saturated subtraction, I was trying if there is some clever trick with mixing saturated subtraction and min/max operations to avoid the comparing and blending, but did not find anything (which does not mean there isn't one).